# Como concatenar dois campos e usar como chave para consulta no proc sql do SAS, assim como é feito no trecho do sql do exemplo?

Tags: sql, sas

Eu preciso transformar o trecho do código SQL abaixo para o formato do PROC SQL no SAS.

No código SQL ficaria assim: `where cod_operadora || '|' || num_contrato in ('003 | 123456789', '001 | 987654321')`

Detalhe: o campo `cod_operadora` é um campo texto e o campo `num_contrato` é um campo numérico.

Como eu poderia converter o trecho do SQL para o PROC SQL do SAS?

Answer (score -1):

Você vai precisar usar a função CONCAT().

Ex: `CONCAT(cod_operadora, ' | ', num_contrato)`

Answer (score -1):

Pode utilizar a função CAT
CAT(Coluna.A || '|'|| Coluna.B) as Concat